How to test whether correcting an experimental response for a function of two controlled variables removes dependency on a controlled variable
I have an experimental setup in which I control two variables (x and y) and measure a third (z). I.e. a two factor response surface.
My hypothesis is that a function of x and y, f(x,y), better explains the response (z) than x does. Furthermore, I hypothesize that correcting the response z for f(x,y) will remove the dependency of z on x. I would like to test these hypotheses statistically but don't know where to start looking.
Edit: Context added in response to comment:
It is an ecotoxicological experiment in which earthworms dwell for seven weeks in different soil and contaminant mixtures, after which the amount of coocoons they've laid will be counted. The soils range from low to high organic matter as well as low to high contaminant concentrations. The organic matter content (y) is expected to both have a direct impact on the amount of coocoons and an indirect impact by modulating the bioavailability of the contaminants in a predictable (modelled) manner.
The bioavailable concentration of the contaminants f(x, y), as modelled and measured, will be expected to determine the toxic response completely, removing any impact of the total toxicant concentration (x) on the amount of coocoons (z) after accounting for the bioavailable toxicant concentration f(x, y).
Any help would be appreciated,
Martin

Hi, welcome to CV! Can you clarify how you control the variables x and y? I.e. can you give more details about your study design?

Thanks for the welcome Sointu! Pleasae let me know if you would like me to elaborate further or clarify anything.

Cool research topic!
Sorry, I may still be understanding incorrectly, but the way I read it you have measured the amount of organic matter content (y) and the amount of toxicant concentration (x) at each earthworm dwelling place. In that case, wouldn't some type of general(ized) linear model predicting the amount of cocoons from y and x suffice?
As the number of cocoons is probably a count variable, perhaps a Poisson regression?
Additionally, do you count each dwelling place as one observation? Meaning, you go to dwelling place A and count the cocoons, and get one number, then you go to dwelling place B, again count the cocoons and get one number etc.? If so, a regular poisson regression should suffice.
If you take several counts from the same dwelling place, then you need to account for the non-independence of separate observations that come from the same dwelling place somehow, for instance by using a GEE model or multilevel poisson regression.
